# drupal user login redirect

Tags: drupal

hi i wrote a module for user page generation. After login the path goes to users/[user-name] and i want to customize it using my module. how to handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Login Toboggan to set a login destination. There are a few modules available for login redirecting without having to code.

To customize the look and feel of the user profile page, you can implement that through a TPL with CSS, or you can use Views to create Content Panes in conjunction with Panels, and override the user/% profile view.

Answer (score 2):

With `hook_form_alter` you can create a submit handler for the login form, and in it set `$form_state['redirect']` to where you want the user to be redirected to when the user logs in.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a hook_user fonction like this

```
function mymodule_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category=NULL) {
 switch ($op) {
  case 'login':  // user just logs in...
                        // Modify $_REQUEST['destination'];
                        // but no drupal_goto in order 
                        // to avoid problem with other hook
   break;
 }
}
```

More here : 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoeFTr124jw

Comment: Using drupal_goto in a hook, is a big NO NO, it'll disrupt other modules implementing hook_user.

Comment: Ok so it's better to use $_REQUEST['destination']. I will change my post.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this and much more with `Login Toboggan`, but if you just want to redirect where users are taken to after logging in try the module Login Destination: [(D6 & D7)](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination)